# Javascript change event target opacity

Tags: javascript

I try to use this code to change opacity to 0.7:

```
//if div hasn't been mouseovered
if(!e.target.getAttribute('data-shade'))
    e.target.style.background = color;
    e.target.setAttribute('datashade', 1);
//else div has been mouse overed
else
    e.target.style.cssText = 'opacity: 0.7';
```

Why does it become white instead?

*sorry bad english

Comment: There are two different property names used at `.getAttribute()` and `.setAttribute()`

Comment: Because you're overriding the entire `cssText` of the `style` element. Set `.style.opacity = '0.7'` instead.

Comment: Are you getting a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else` error by any chance?

Comment: @guest271314 `.getAttribute()` to check if data-shade has any value `.setAttribute()` to set the value
@Teemu it became grey instead, and get whiter if i decrease the opacity
@AlonEitan no, sir.